# RxAndroid - how to throw fatal exceptions after onCompleted()

Tags: java, android, exception, rx-java, rx-android

We are using RxAndroid + retrofit for our api calls.

I sort of understand why any exceptions within the sequence will pass the Throwable through onError().

But how do you end the sequence, how do you then process a response and return to throwing fatal exceptions again?  I would have expected processing in onCompleted() would allow this, but I'm still seeing onError() being called.

Simplified snippet below.  Gives the result -

```html
throwable: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

```html
        Observable<ResponseModel> observable = getApiCallObservable();
        AppObservable.bindFragment(this, observable)
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<ResponseModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        uninitializedList.add("item");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "throwable: " + e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(ResponseModel response) {
        
                    }
                });
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure i understood what is being asked here. Basically, if your Observable `getApiCallObservable()` throws an error, onError will be called and you should handle the error accordingly in `onError`. If that happens, as it is, nothing will happen anymore. If an error happens, `onError` is called and stream end. If there is no error, `onNext` is called, and that's where you should do anything with your response. After `onNext`, finally, `onCompleted` is called.

The error that is showing is simply saying that your arraylist `uninitializedList` is null, so the method call `add()` is invalid.

Edit. I think i got your point now. You want handle the error without onError being called by the observable. Move your oncomplete code to onNext, and it won't fall under onError, it will throw the fatal exception. is that it?

Comment: Tried moving to onComplete, again onError gets calls with an npe.   Basically I want the app to crash when an exception happens.. For example if I get a api response to persist in the db.   I don't want Rx to handle db exceptions or any other crashes along the way.   I want Rx to be contained to api calls only.

Comment: move your code to onNext as i said. use subscribeOn(Schedulers.io) and observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.newThread). It should fix the issue i think